# Can SPFx Webpart and Extension exist in a single app?

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-extensions

I'm starting to get my hands on using the new SharePoint Framework.

I have general ideas about how they work now but I couldn't any document or statement that they (Client Web Part and Extension) could be in a same solution/app to deploy together.

If anyone could point me to the right way that would be awesome !!.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can have multiple webparts or extensions in the same solution. Think of it as a Visual Studio solution with multiple projects (i.e one sln file and multiple dlls).

To add a webpart/extension in the existing solution, you simply need to run the yeoman generator again.

`yo @microsoft/sharepoint` - run this command in your current solution and the generator is intelligent enough to add the webpart/extension. It internally checks for config.json file and if it exists appends the new "project" there.

[image]

To see those, 2 for example(1 webpart and 1 extension), you can go to the `config > config.json` file. In that file, you will see it as below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create as many web parts or extensions on a single solution. You can watch this SharePoint PnP video to know more about that. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sm5UocF8mcQ